# How to handle MYSQL search query , if search paramter is null

Tags: mysql

if I am searching record by **phone** without ClinicName, MySQL throws an error same as vice versa, if a search by **clinicName** without phoneNo.

Here is the query I am using :

```
    SELECT UL.Id,IFNULL(UL.FirstName, '') AS FirstName,
    IFNULL(UL.Specialties, '') AS Specialties 
    FROM UserLogins UL 
    WHERE 1 OR
    UL.PhoneNo LIKE '%".$phoneNo."%' 
    OR
    UL.ClinicName LIKE '%".$clinicName."%)
```

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: this code is **vulnerable** to **sql injection** so use only **prepared statements with parameters** also read up on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and make a [mre]

Comment: Actually, I am using the Laravel Framework, and laravel is automatically handle the SQL injection stuff on there own.

Comment: So I make a simple query, and my question is that if I search with a phone number without a clinic name, means the clinic name receives null.